# how to get Emacs message-mode to kill message buffer on send?

Tags: emacs, elisp

In Emacs, I'm using `message-mode` to compose and send email. When I do `mail-send` (<kbd>C-c C-c</kbd>), it sends my message and buries the buffer, and the buffer is still lurking in the background.

How do I instruct Emacs to kill the buffer upon `mail-send`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `customize` to set `message-kill-buffer-on-exit` to `t` or add

```
(custom-set-variables '(message-kill-buffer-on-exit t))
```

to your `.emacs`.